# Crystal reports 2008 sp5 generates a corrupt word document

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, ms-word, corrupt

Since last updates of a Crystal report, I have about problem when a word file generation.
The word document is corrupt and I can not find on the web the sollution or a similar problem. 
I can generate a PDF document without problem. 
The document is corrupt with Word, but I can opens with WordPad.

the resulting file is .doc corrupted without error on my code

```
try
{
    t = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.WordForWindows;
    content_type = "application/msword";
    var oStream = MonReport.ExportToStream(t);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[oStream.Length];
    oStream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oStream.Length - 1));


    parent.Response.ClearContent();
    parent.Response.ClearHeaders();

    parent.Response.ContentType = content_type;

    parent.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    parent.Response.Flush();
    parent.Response.Close();
    MonReport.Close();
    MonReport.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your length is 1 too short. That should be:

```
oStream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oStream.Length));
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)'s third parameter is

> "The maximum number of bytes to be read from the current stream."

Comment: thanks to whoever revenge downvoted on a clearly correct answer.